# Traefik Proxy update response cookies SameSite to None

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, traefik, openam, samesite

I have Traefik Proxy in front of several web apps and I want to be able to modify the response to the client so that all cookies have SameSite set to None.

This is because Google Chrome is blocking cookies within iframes for my web apps that use external Single Sign On (SSO) services, eg. OpenAM.

An example for APACHE WEB SERVER would be the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1; Secure; SameSite=None"
        Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1; Secure; SameSite=None"
</IfModule>
```

Is this possible in Traefik using configuration labels set on the web app services? Or a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I posted to the [Traefik community forums](https://community.traefik.io/t/traefik-proxy-update-response-cookies-samesite-to-none/18153) and got the advice to look into plugins. I learned how to create my own plugin to do specifically what I wanted and it worked!

Comment: Could you please share your plugin code?